# Can't leave the OS X Developer Beta, no option to do so in App Store preferences

Tags: macos, beta, osx-elcapitan

I've had my system on the OS X developer beta but have now installed the released version of El Capitan, and I'd like to leave the Beta program now.

Oddly the preferences pane for App Store doesn't have the entire row that [this article](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/unenroll) details, so I can't change this.

I can't find another way to leave the Beta

Edit: I know I'm still signed up because I just got the system update notification for the developer beta 10.11.1

Edit: App Store preferences without the pre-release option
[image]

Comment: How do you know you're still on the Beta-program?

Comment: I'm getting the updates offered to me in App Store > Updates. Specifically '...developer beta 10.11.1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn it off in System settings.

[image]

EDIT:
If you can't see it there then hit this command

sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL

or manually edit

sudo vim /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist

Comment: Please read my question and detail in full. I felt I clearly stated that this response isn't helpful as the 'Your computer is set to receive pre-release Software Update seeds' row isn't visible in my App Store preferences

Comment: defaults write com.apple.appstore HidePrereleaseOSUpdates -bool YES What about this one?

Comment: And the link at the bottom https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/unenroll#

Comment: I had already unenrolled online via the link, but unfortunately your `defaults write..` suggestion hasn't worked, even after a restart. Thanks for the tips

Comment: Perfect, `sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL` worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Same, thank you! If only there's a way to run that on my iPhone, as I'm stuck in the same problem. Profile is deleted, but beta software update still showing up

Comment: This also worked for me, thanks